# Does a list of canonical questions for Super User exist?

Tags: discussion, canonical-answer

When reviewing questions I often run across ones I *think* should already have a canonical answer, but I'm still new enough to the site that I don't know for sure.  Not wanting to answer if the question should be flag as a duplicate, I go about searching the site (you know, what the *poster* ought to have done). This can be pretty time consuming and if there's a list of canonical questions I could refer to, that would be helpful*.

- I've looked for a tag that would identify such questions and found none.
- I've searched Meta SU as well as examined questions in the [canonical-answer] tag
- I also search Meta SE

As I was writing this question, I found the [community-faq] tag on SU.  It has 30 questions in it.  Is *this* what I'm looking for?

<sub>*I'm not implying the only questions that should be flagged as duplicate are ones with canonical answers. Rather, some questions betray their commonality so plainly that answering with anything short of a canonical answer doesn't make sense.</sub>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it is. [community-faq](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/community-faq) is where the canonical questions/answers are. In general, for a new canonical question/answer, asking on meta first and getting community feedback is a good idea.

Comment: **asking on meta first** -- Good to know. You've rightly guessed I may run across the need to add canonical answers so knowing the process is most helpful.

Comment: Yup. That and "Yes you're right" is too short for the lameness filter ;)

Comment: Don't forget [tag:community-faq-proposed] either!

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi Please explain that tag to me. Can I tag a question with it if I think it should be considered for the FAQ, or should I first bring it up on meta?

Comment: @Twisty In short: Simply tag it, and if it gets good answers, it will be retagged into a [tag:community-faq]. For more info, see the tag wiki: http://superuser.com/tags/community-faq-proposed/info. With that being said, you should probably raise a meta question too in order to get a consensus toward creating one and to get attention to it once it's created.